# Funcanimation Stop in Python 2.7 Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I had build a GUI using tkinter and pyhton2.7, I already got success in plotting a data (using Matplotlib) coming from my serial port in my GUI. A snap of my code is as follow:

```
""All required import was done here"" 

x = []
adc_data = []
q = [0]


f = plt.Figure(figsize = (9,5), dpi = 100)
ax = f.add_subplot(111)


class ADC_Ref_Data(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_geometry(self, '900x600+200+150')
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "ADC Referene")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)

        self.frames[StartPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)


        self.button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Start",
                        command=lambda: self.start())
        self.button4.place(relx = 0.03, rely = 0.95,  height = 30 , width = 80 , anchor = 'sw')


        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.48, relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.8, anchor = 'center' )



    def animate(self,i):
        while self.button4['text'] == 'Pause':
            self.ser.write(str(chr(250)))
            data = self.ser.read(1)
            data1 = self.ser.read(1)

            LSB = ord(data)
            MSB = ord(data1)

            dec = 256*MSB+LSB
            q[0] = q[0]+1
            x.append(q[0]) #adding data to list
            adc_data.append(dec) #adding data to list
            plt.pause(1)

            ax.clear()
            a = ax.plot(x,adc_data,'^r')

    def start(self):
        if self.button4['text'] == 'Start':
            ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, self.animate,init_func=self.init,frames = 10, interval=1000)#,blit = True)
            f.canvas.show()


app = ADC_Ref_Data()
app.mainloop()
```

from the above code as you can see that whenever I press Start Button on my Gui it will call a function "Start", in which Funcanimation is called and a graph is plotted continuously (in an infinite loop). Now I wanted to stop this Funcanimation, when I press a stop button.

How can I stop that running Funcanimation?

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `animate()` should only return new data and `ani` should use this data to draw new frame of animation. now you use `while` in `animate()` and you do all animaton on your own - this way you don't need `FuncAnimation`

Comment: you can stop repeating animation using `ani.repeat = False` but I think your `animate()` function is incorrect - it should get new data end return `adc_data`. `FuncAnimation` gets this data, clears plot, draws new data, makes pause, and then it calls `animate()` again for new data.

Answer (score 0):

try
`ani.event_source.stop()`
`ani.event_source.start()`